# Do you need to eat a kezayis of the ikar to make a bracha acharona necessitated by the ikar?

Tags: halacha, blessing, mezonot-beracha, ikar-tofel, shehakol-beracha

Say you're eating a mixture of something requiring a mezonot blessing mixed with something requiring a shechakol blessing. By the rules of ikar and tafel you would just say a mezonot on the entire mixture - granted all the rules of ikar and tafel are in effect.

With this being the case, do you need to eat a kezayis of the ikar part in order to justify reciting an al hamichya or is it enough to eat a kezayis of the entire mixture (with some parts being non-mezonot) in order to say the al hamichya?

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to eat a kezayis of the ikar part in order to justify reciting the appropriate after-blessing for the ikar part.

The source is [Iggeros Moshe OC 4 (42)](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14677&st=&pgnum=75) . Rav Feinstein ז״ל deals with the case where a person eats less than a kzayis of salty fish (the ikkar in this case) and a kzayis of bread afterwards (as the tofel). (See the example in [OC 212](http://mishnaberura.eu5.org/).)

The questioner asks if the after-brocho is birkas hamozon or borei nefoshos. Rav Feinstein paskens that the after-brocho is borei nefoshos. (See  the teshuva for why.)

Comment: This is only true in that situation. If the Ikkur would require an al hamichya but was not a kizayis and only with the tafful completes a kizayis, we would have an argument between the kitzur and Reb Moshe.