# Shiur Brocha Achrona 2 different foods

Tags: halacha, blessing, food, fruits

If I eat less than a k’zayis of cake; and less than a k’zayis of grapes; do I make a brocha Achrona? And if I do; is it Borei Nefushois, or Ahl Hamichya V’ahl hu’aitz?

Comment: Similar https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/26438/759

Answer (score 3, accepted):

R Chaim Gross and R Shraga Simmons answer this question in their series on blessings ([here](http://www.aish.com/jl/jewish-law/blessings/33-Bracha-Achrona-on-Mixtures.html)) quoting [Mishna Brura 210:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.210.1?lang=bi&p2=Mishnah_Berurah.210.1&lang2=bi)

> [What is the blessing if] you ate a half-kezayit of crackers and a half-kezayit of apple? **The
>   proper bracha achrona is Borei Nefashot.** The reason is because the
>   apple cannot "go up" in status to combine and obligate Al HaMichya,
>   but the cracker can "go down" to obligate a Borei Nefashot.

This is also the ruling of Kitzur Shulchan Aruch ([51:4](https://www.sefaria.org/Kitzur_Shulchan_Aruch.51.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))

> So, if you ate half a kazayis of something that requires the
>   after-berachah, Borei nefashos rabbos, [and then you ate] another half
>   a kazayis of a food after which the "three-faceted" [after-]
>   berachah, is said or even if you ate half a kazayis of bread, **you
>   recite the after-berachah, Borei nefashos rabbos. And it seems to me
>   that the same ruling applies if you ate half a kazayis of fruit after
>   which the berachah Al ha'eitz is said, together with half a kazayis of
>   food after which the berachah Al hamichyah is said.**

[This site](http://www.berachot.org/halacha/15_brachaachrona.html) mentions R Shlomo Zalman Auerbach disagrees and recommends "*al hamichiya v'al haeitz*" but I haven't yet seen it "inside".

Comment: See שו''ת יביע אומר ח''י סימן יט אות ו' for an interesting psak(that I didn't understand); if you're interested.